# i can't vardump the a variable which was included in other PHP file

Tags: php

[Please have a look at screen shot first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViRAQ.png)

Here's what i have inside in `api.php`

```
$ytapiurl = "rawdata.json";
$http_request_api = file_get_contents($ytapiurl);
$response = json_decode($http_request_api, true);
```

I have included the `api.php` in `header.php` and when I `var_dump($reponse['link'][22]);`
 it in `api.php`, I get the right output, but when I do the same thing (`var_dump($reponse['link'][22]);`) in `header.php` I get this error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(rawdata.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in includes/api.php on line 25

Can someone suggest a solution please!

Comment: Most likely, the path to rawdata.json is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When using `include` or `require` (and their `_once` derivatives) *without* an absolute path defined, among a few previous options such as the include path, PHP [will use the directory **that the called script is executing from to determine the current absolute path.**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#107685) So when you load `header.php` which includes `includes/api.php`, it will be as if the `api.php` has been copied and pasted into the `header.php` all along. Therefore PHP will look for the `rawdata.json` file in the folder that `header.php` is located in.

To fix this, you should be using absolute path references at all times. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is a good one to work with. This may need to be modified depending on what your `docroot` is:

```
$ytapiurl = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/rawdata.json';
```

From the PHP doc comment I referenced (this explains it well):

> Remember that if file A includes file B, and B includes file C; the include path in B should take into account that A, not B, is the active working directory.

Comment: I have copied the JSON file to ROOT Directory of application i got the right output but now i'm getting this error
`Notice: Undefined variable: $response in header.php on line 6`

Comment: @HassanNaseer I can't diagnose code that I can't see. Post your `header.php` in your question.

Comment: `<?php

//Required Files Includes for Application
include 'includes/api.php';
$sitetitle = "Bit Watch";
var_dump($reponse['link'][22]);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1">
    <title><?php echo $sitetitle ?></title>
    <link href="static/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <link href="static/css/boo2tstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Video Playing - Responsive Layout - v0.1-->
</head>`

Comment: @HassanNaseer `var_dump($reponse['link'][22]);` is a typo. Change it to `var_dump($response['link'][22]);`

Comment: it's in my `header.php`

Comment: @HassanNaseer Also change your `include` to `require` just in case the file isn't being loaded correctly, so PHP will throw an error if so.